# Exception on file processing response to web service query

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am using the mule flow specified below to make a simple request of a web service. The request goes out successfully and with wireshark I see what looks like a proper response.

I saw no exception until I included an output file endpoint (in order to capture the response to file). Even with this exception (included at bottom), when I look into the output file that is generated I see my data though in many cases its only part of the data.

What is causing this exception?

This is the flow:

```
<flow name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1" doc:name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="gen" repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" 
        doc:name="Quartz"> <quartz:event-generator-job /> </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="wsdl.Payload" doc:name="Java"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="listTest"
        clientClass="server.TestService_Service" port="TestServicePort"
        wsdlLocation="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService?wsdl"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAPY" />
    <outbound-endpoint
        address="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService"
        doc:name="HTTP"  mimeType="text/xml" />
    <logger message="Received HTTP Response #[payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\tmp" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt" 
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Output File" /> 
</flow>
```

This is the exception:

```
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,753 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02]    org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: soap payload:      org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$1@69d7ef58
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,769 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,769 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,769 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,769 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'HTTP_HTTPS.dispatcher.479670620'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,784 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'HTTP_HTTPS.dispatcher.479670620'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,878 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Received HTTP Response org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@5e8aa5e1
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,878 [[test_auditor_client4].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.784931034'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,878 [[test_auditor_client4].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.784931034'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-02-21 15:38:09,894 [[test_auditor_client4].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\tmp\21-02-13_1361479089894.txt
WARN  2013-02-21 15:38:09,894 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://server/}TestService#{http://server/}listTest has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't parse stream.
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1181)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:280)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at $Proxy33.listTest(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithProxy(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:187)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:129)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:93)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:186)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:179)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:178)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:536)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:585)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:610)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:316)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1179)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.isReadAllowed(AutoCloseInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
    at org.mule.model.streaming.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:63)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.BaseReader.readBytes(BaseReader.java:155)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.loadMore(UTF8Reader.java:368)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:111)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.initialLoad(ReaderBootstrapper.java:250)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(ReaderBootstrapper.java:133)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:531)
    ... 54 more
ERROR 2013-02-21 15:38:09,972 [[test_auditor_client4].TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Attempted read on closed stream.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Attempted read on closed stream. (java.io.IOException)
  org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream:183 (null)
2. Attempted read on closed stream. (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException)
  com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory:536 (null)
3. Couldn't parse stream. (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils:1181 (null)
4. Couldn't parse stream. (javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException)
  org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy:156 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.html)
5. Attempted read on closed stream.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:148 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.isReadAllowed(AutoCloseInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:107)
    at org.mule.model.streaming.DelegatingInputStream.read(DelegatingInputStream.java:63)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the result of the HTTP outbound interaction is first processed by what's after the outbound endpoint before being passed back to the CXF client. At this time, the streaming payload has been consumed and CXF can't deal with it anymore.

Can you try the following:

```
<flow name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1" doc:name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="gen" repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" 
        doc:name="Quartz"> <quartz:event-generator-job /> </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="wsdl.Payload" doc:name="Java"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService"
        doc:name="HTTP"  mimeType="text/xml">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="listTest"
            clientClass="server.TestService_Service" port="TestServicePort"
            wsdlLocation="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService?wsdl"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAPY" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Received HTTP Response #[payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\tmp"
        outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt" 
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Output File" /> 
</flow>
```

The idea is to localize the CXF interaction to the HTTP endpoint.

Note that I have changed the generic outbound endpoint into an HTTP one, it's not compulsory but at least you'll get better support for the available properties.

Also note that the message payload in the flow after the CXF interaction will be the response object, not the SOAP message. You'll have to decide on a serialization strategy (like JAXB) to save it in file.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll give this a try this morning.

Comment: I've tried the flow that you suggest, the error that I see now is:

ERROR 2013-02-22 09:29:41,918 [[test_auditor_client4].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 

Message               : An invalid return type "class java.io.InputStream" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-266

Comment: Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type "class java.io.InputStream" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
 at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:122)
 at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:411)
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:362)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Comment: thanks david.. you steered me in the right direction. I've just figured out the magic, its actually pretty sweet. I'll post the flow and the class that i use  to request the service operation and to process the response

Answer (score 0):

Now that David has taken the time to steer me in the right direction, I'll post the answer for the benefit of those that try this in the future:

The working flow is:

```
<flow name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1" doc:name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="gen"
        repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="wsdl.Payload" doc:name="Java" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService"
        doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="listTest"
            clientClass="server.TestService_Service" port="TestServicePort"
            wsdlLocation="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService?wsdl"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAPY" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Received HTTP Response #[payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="wsdl.Payload" doc:name="Java"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\tmp"
        outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Output File" />
</flow>
```

Notice that I use a class wsdl.Payload both prior to the HTTP request, and subsequent to the request. This single class is used to generate the request and to handle the response.

This is that class:

```
package wsdl;

import server.ListTest;
import server.ListTestResponse;

public class Payload {

    public ListTest request() {
    System.out.println("request response");
    return new ListTest();
}

public String response(ListTestResponse listTestResponse) {
    System.out.println("process response");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    List<Test> testList = listTestResponse.getReturn();
    Iterator<Test> testIt = testList.iterator();
    while(testIt.hasNext()) {
        Test test = testIt.next();
        sb.append(test.getName()).append(" ").append(test.getDescription()).append(", ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Voila, now the mule flow works exactly as I intended.